# Подскажите как написать функцию insert для forward list?

Tags: c++, списки, insert, односвязный-список

мне подсказали что можно как-то так, но тут запутанно, не совсем пойму:

```
struct Node{
  int value;
  Node* next;
  Node* prev;
};
void insert(Node*n, int val)
{
  Node*a = new Node;
  n->next = a;
  a->next = n->next;
  a->value = val;
  n->value = a->value;
}
```

Comment: `forward_list` это односвязный список. У него не должно быть ссылки на предыдущий элемент. А если такая ссылка есть, то это уже двусвязный список, т.е. `list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тогда уж так:

```
void insert(Node*n, int val)
{
    Node*a = new Node;
    a->value = val;
    a->next = n->next;
    n->next = a;

    a->prev = n;                    // Не нужно для односвязного списка
    if (a->next) a->next->prev = a; // Не нужно для односвязного списка

}
```

Т.е. вы просто вставляете после `n` новый узел, обновляя соответствующим образом поля `n` и `a`. `n` теперь указывает на `a`, а `a` - куда раньше указывал `n`.

Comment: сперва а указывает куда раньше n указывал, а потом n на а, да?

Comment: и не имеет значения, если сперва указать место, потом присвоить значение и наоборот?

Comment: и то что я написал в вопросе, это правильно?

Comment: а если допустим не после n вставлять, а перед?

Comment: if (a->next) значит пока а->next != null?

Comment: Не пока, а если. Если перед n - в односвязном нужно пройти весь список в поисках узла, для которого `next` даст `n`, и вставлять после него. У вас - ну смотрите сами: `n->next = a;
  a->next = n->next;` второе присваивание заставит `a->next` указывать на `a` - разве это правильно?...

Comment: да, спасибо) а деструктор нужно циклом и итератором осуществить? или могу взять head->next пока не будет 0 и применять функцию deleteNod(у меня есть она)?

Comment: ~F_list(){
  while(head->next != nullptr)
    deleteNod(head->next);
  deleteInd(head);
}

Comment: или уже в конце deleteNod(head) не нужно делать, не потеряли так его сначала?